# Debug Error when invoking destructor with delete

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyString {
private:
    char* Buffer;

public:
    MyString(const char* InitialInput){
        if(InitialInput){
            Buffer = new char[strlen(InitialInput + 1)];
            strcpy_s(Buffer, strlen(InitialInput) + 1, InitialInput);
        } else { Buffer = NULL; }
    }
    ~MyString(){ if(Buffer){ delete Buffer; } }

    int GetLength(){ return strlen(Buffer); }
    const char* GetString() { return Buffer; }
};

void UseMyString(MyString const& Input) {
    cout << "String buffer in MyString is " << Input.GetLength() << " characters long." << endl;
    cout << "Buffer contains: " << Input.GetString() << endl;
}

int main(){
    MyString SayHello("Hello from String Class");
    UseMyString(SayHello);

    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl4Nz.jpg

Two objects with different char* Buffer are created.
However, it is unable to delete the Buffer.
If I comment out

```
    if (Buffer != NULL)
        delete Buffer;
```

the program run through.
So why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allocate memory with `buffer = new char[length]` you should free memory with `delete[] buffer;`

But there are other problems in your code. Why don't you want to simply use `std::string` ? It will certainly be more efficient...

I can't compile your code either (I don't use windows) but I have issues with `strcpy_s` and `strlen` and there are also issues with type conversion.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow. I don't know how to use code tag in comment.

The delete[] is the problem. Thanks

I don't the std::string because I am creating a program to learn how copy constructor work. I need pointer inside the class. 
char* is just for convenient.

I am using VS2013.It's working after modify the code.lol

Comment: @tom, glad I could help. I guessed that you were not using the same compiler than me, therefore I guessed that I would work only by correcting the `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Buffer = new char[strlen(CopySource.Buffer + 1)];
```

should be:

```
Buffer = new char[strlen(CopySource.Buffer) + 1];
```

In each case where it shows up.

This is in addition to the problem that @PinkFloyd pointed out.